# Django 1.11 how to resolve list_filter duplicates

Tags: django, list, filter, admin

In my Model, a *__str__(self)* that derives the quarter and year from the *DateTimeField* of when Response was *created*.

**Models.py**

```
class Response(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        msg = u"Q%d %d" %(((self.created.month-1)//3)+1, self.created.year)
        return msg
```

In Admin, I want to be able to filter records based on the Quarter in which they were submitted (actually, I want to filter by who *hasn't* submitted a Response for a particular quarter, which I think I can achieve with a well placed tilde later), so I have the following:

**Admin.py**

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('username', 'latest_response')
    list_filter = ('response__created', 'response')

    def latest_response(self, obj):
        return obj.response_set.latest('created')
```

I have submitted four responses so far in testing (through the *def __str__* I have 2 x "Q1 2018", and 2 x " - "), and the result looks like this:

[image: UserAdmin table and list_filter result]

Any ideas why I am getting 3 x "Q1 2018" and 1 x " - "? I want Only 1 x "Q1 2018" in the filter list

Bonus question - any idea how to set a limit to the number of items listed in the filter_list (by response)? I want to limit them to the latest 4 which, might be problematic as I'm using a string.

**EDIT**

Just noticed in the console log that the filters are using a GET request based on the Response ID:

```
"GET /admin/auth/user/?response__id__exact=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 14277
"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3217
"GET /admin/auth/user/?response__id__exact=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 14277
"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3217
"GET /admin/auth/user/?response__id__exact=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 14270
"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3217
"GET /admin/auth/user/?response__isnull=True HTTP/1.1" 200 14599
"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3217
```

So, as I understand it, the *by response* filter is displaying the common name (Q1 2018) for four object's (distinguished by their ID).

How do I go about filtering the objects based on their common name/self? I guess via another def to the Response class?

Comment: have you tried distinct?

Comment: I don't think that would change it, but I will give it a shot. See updated question - I have noticed in the console that the request generated when you filter is tied to a response id (each of them being distinct).

Comment: Usually I reserve the __str__ to a specific identification for my class.... you can create another def quarter(self), for your quarter, and filter over it

Comment: @Walucas I was just about to try that - makes sense. Add that as an answer and I'll check in with the results later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I reserve the `def __str__(self):` as an identification for my class.
Create a

```
def Quarter(self): 
    msg = u"Q%d %d" %(((self.created.month-1)//3)+1, self.created.year)
    return msg
```

And then use that to filter:

```
list_filter = ('response__created', 'Quarter')
```

Comment: I really thought this would work, but unfortunately get the following error - FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'quarter' into field. Choices are: answers, created, id, interview_uuid, survey, survey_id, updated, user, user_id. It's accessing the Response model (fields created, id, interview_uuid, survey, updated, user) but not the Quarter def? (I did try with caps first)

Comment: did you remove the     def latest_response(self, obj):? this error is due to this I think

Comment: Yes it was. This answer helped sort it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666112/4916945