# Django 1.11 admin list_filter to include fields in another model

Tags: django, model, admin

I have a Django Admin class that displays all registered Users. I want to add a column next to each user that displays their latest Response (it's a survey app).

What I've tried so far is:

**Response Model**

```
class Response(models.Model):

    """
        A Response object is a collection of questions and answers with a
        unique interview uuid.
    """

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, related_name="responses")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    interview_uuid = models.CharField(_(u"Interview unique identifier"),
                                      max_length=36)

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name = _('response')
        verbose_name_plural = _('responses')

    def Quarter(self):
        msg = u"Q%d %d" %(((self.created.month-1)//3)+1, self.created.year)
        return msg
```

**Admin.py**

```
class ResponseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('survey', 'created', 'user', 'Quarter') **works here

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'latest_response')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'latest_response')

    def latest_response(self, obj):
    (return "Quarter" from Response Model) **how do I get it to work here too?

admin.site.register(Response, ResponseAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

A few of my attempts resulted in the following error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Quarter' into field. Choices are: answers, created, id, interview_uuid, survey, survey_id, updated, user, user_id
```

So I can see the issue is that UserAdmin isn't getting the Quarter field from the Response Model for some reason. When I change *def Quarter(self)* to *__str__(self)*, it displays as I want in the UserAdmin, but then I have an issue with filtering.

Under the ResponseAdmin class, Quarter works as I want it. How can I use the Quarter field in UserAdmin as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def latest_response(self, obj):
    latest_resp = (
        Response.objects
        .filter(user=obj)
        .order_by('-created')
        .first()
    )

    if latest_resp is not None:
        return latest_resp.Quarter()
```

Comment: Wow, that's really cool - very useful if I ever want to pull in fields from a different model in future. Thank you. The only bit that doesn't make immediate sense is .filter(user=obj) - could you elaborate please?

Comment: @RonaldGreeff In UserAdmin class, obj will be a User object. We want to get latest response for this user, so we filter responses by user first, order descending by created date and take first one (latest one).